# HTML to wordpress Converting Pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm just a little confused with converting HTML to WordPress.

I have the following HTML pages "About us, Contact Us , Team"  etc...

in WordPress do I have too create "About us.php, Contact Us.php , Team.php"
or
create a ContentPage.php and on wordpress I create the pages "About us, Contact Us , Team

---

I was also thinking of creating "About us.php, Contact Us.php , Team.php" then a tag should added where the user can change the text

Can't find a tutorial on a explanation on this.

Comment: You may take a look from this link, a lot of tutorials regarding wordress: http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/wordpress-tutorials-designers-1012990

Comment: Thanks :), those are more Wordpress only tutorials, I am looking for html too wordpress tutorials , thanks for the idea though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to create separate `php` files for each page, instead, you can create a `page.php` file for all of your pages to be used when any page is displayed and to create pages from Wordpress' admin panel from `Pages` menu. If you have a `page.php` file in your template folder then `WordPress` will use this template to show every pages otherwise, the `index.php` file would be used. You can also create custom page templates for specific pages. An example/structure of a basic page template (without any formatting and `HTML` tags)

```
get_header(); // adds the header (header.php)
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    the_title(); // prints title of the page

    the_content(); // prints content/body of the page

endwhile; endif;

get_sidebar(); // adds the sidebar (sidebar.php)
get_footer(); // adds the footer (footer.php)
```

These are common structure and functions used for a template file but you should read on Codex for more information about [creating a page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and add `formatting/HTML` according to your site's layout. Also, check [Convert HTML to WordPress](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/) and [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

Comment: Thanks :) i Finally get it now.its just like creating a templete for all other pages too follow (e.g. asp frames) a few other links that helped [Link 1](http://www.wphub.com/tutorials/convert-a-html-template-into-a-wordpress-theme/) [Link 2](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/15/migrate-existing-website-to-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways...

1. Hire a freelancer
2. Convert manually by referring to [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/)
3. Use an automatic converter. This is the best I've found: https://htmltowordpress.io